# CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout scroll momentum

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement a CollapsingToolbarLayout with a TabLayout below. Right now, when I scroll up on the tablayout, the scroll momentum stops at the top of the viewpager for the tablayout. What I want is what is implemented in the Yahoo! Sports app shown here:

TabLayout scrolled:
[image: TabLayout scrolled]

TabLayout reached top and begins to expand toolbar:
[image: TabLayout reached top and begins to expand toolbar]

toolbar now fully expanded from scroll momentum of TabLayout:
[image: toolbar now fully expanded from scroll momentum of TabLayout]

Basically, I am wanting the momentum from the scrolling of the viewpager to transition to the CollapsingToolbarLayout once it has reached the top of the viewpager. I DO NOT want the CollapsingToolbarLayout to expand with any viewpager up scroll, but only once it has reached the top. Right now my viewpager reaches the top, all scroll momentum is lost, and I have to scroll again to expand the toolbar.

If you need my code I can provide it later, but I don't think it's required, as my CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout implementation is pretty generic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3-4 variations available for Scroll_Flags. You can select whichever suits you the most.

```
Scroll || EnterAlways

Scroll || EnterAlwaysCollapsed

Scroll || ExitUntilCollapsed
```

Comment: I am aware of these. None of them provide the behavior described.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out these issues I am facing have been addressed in new versions of the Android sdk:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-2

I simply updated from sdk 25 to 27 and these issues were solved and now my view behaves like the example above. If you have having these issues UPDATE TO ANDROID SDK 27 before spending hours pulling your hair out. Good Luck!